# Cannot get chosen.js to work when using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, capybara, jquery-chosen

I am currently trying  to write a test using Capybara in a Rails application. My issue is I have a drop down menu using chosen.js. I am able to get Capybara to select the correct user but I am unable to trigger the coffeescript associated when a user is selected.

From my test
`select_from_chosen(/\Anormal1\z/, from: 'history-users')`

In test_helper.rb

```
def select_from_chosen(item_text, options)
  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
  field_id = find_field(options[:from])[:id]
  within "#history_users_chosen" do
    find('a.chosen-single').click
    input = find("div.chosen-search input")
    find('ul.chosen-results').click
    within 'a.chosen-single' do
      page.should have_content item_text
    end
  end
  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
end
```

From coffeescript

```
$("#history-users").chosen
    width: '250px'
    search_contains: true
    disable_search_threshold: 10
    no_results_text: 'No users match'
    placeholder_text_single: 'Choose a user...'
  .change ->
    refreshMap()

refreshMap = (userid) ->
    selected = $(".chosen-select")[0].selectedOptions[0]
    userid = $(selected).data 'user-id'
    if typeof userid != "undefined"
      date = moment $("#datepicker").datepicker 'getDate'
      after = date.format 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z'
      before = date.add 'days', 1
        .format 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z'
```

The error I get is:
`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$(".chosen-select")[0].selectedOptions')`

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$(".chosen-select")[0].selectedOptions')`

I apologize in advance if this has already been answered somewhere or if this doesn't make sense. Thank you.